# Get all the days of the interval dates

Tags: php, datetime

I have two `DateTime` objects, `dateFrom` and `dateTo`.

```
DateTime {#549 ▼
  +"date": "2015-02-26 00:00:00.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "Europe/Helsinki"
}

DateTime {#608 ▼
  +"date": "2015-02-28 00:00:00.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "Europe/Helsinki"
}
```

I want to get something like this:

> 26 Jan
>
> 27 Jan
>
> 28 Jan

how can I do this?

Comment: These datetime objects look like javascript objects. Are they? Or is this server side?

Comment: it's server side. tag "php"

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this can help you:

`$.datepicker.parseDate( format, value, settings )` - Extract a date from a string value with a specified format.

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: What does jQuery have to do with an question tagged PHP datetime?

Comment: Sorry, the format is posted is like a javascript format, that's because i post with jquery, my mistake !, sorry !, also he dind't mention the format is trying for...

Comment: Yeah it's not clear from his post what he means. But he tags it with PHP.... well lets see what he has to add to the question. I'll remove my downvote when possible.